# Algebra QF $f(x)=x^2-18x-4$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the problem to find the zero of the function:
$$f(x)=x^2-18x-4$$

I have it mostly worked out as $a=1, b= -18, c= -4$

worked out I have:

$$\frac{18\pm \sqrt{340}}{2}$$

I know the answers are 
$$9+ \sqrt{85}\\
9- \sqrt{85}$$

The question is when working the problem out I end up with:

$$\frac{18\pm \sqrt{340}}{2}$$

I am not sure how that step (with  √ 340) becomes $9\pm\sqrt{85}$

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to divide by $2a$ when applying the quadratic formula.

Comment: Hint: $340=4\times 85$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

$$\frac{18\pm\sqrt{340}}{2}=\frac{18\pm\sqrt{4\cdot85}}{2}=\frac{18\pm\sqrt{4}\cdot\sqrt{85}}{2}=\frac{18\pm2\sqrt{85}}{2}=\frac{2\cdot(9\pm\sqrt{85})}{2}=9\pm\sqrt{85}$$